# Error when searching without any results

Tags: search

I have one last error on my Wordpress blog that I can't solve myself.

The searching for something without any results, the following error occurs

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for get_page_id(), called in /var/www/titanen.dk/public_html/spillersmart/wp-content/themes/WPTube4/functions.php on line 262 and defined in /var/www/titanen.dk/public_html/spillersmart/wp-content/themes/WPTube4/functions.php on line 237
```

My functions.php file can be seen here http://spillersmart.dk/functions.txt

Do you guys know what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: Not shure if I close vote with _off topic_ or _too localized_.

Answer (score 0):

You call `$page_current_id = get_page_id();` in `tube_getcustomfield()`. Add a `name` to this call.

This isn’t exactly a WordPress question. ;)

Comment: I didn't know where else to ask, sorry :-) What do you mean by add a nem to my call?

Comment: You cannot call a function with a _required_ parameter without parameters. You could use `get_page_id( get_the_title() );` or something similar, but leaving the call blank cannot work. The best place to ask PHP syntax questions is still Stackoverflow, I guess.